# Can not open web link from Instant App Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-apps

I am having a problem opening urls in web browser from Instant App. The code that works on the regular app catches ActivityNotFoundExeption.
Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong and how to fix it?
Before anyone asks, the link in storeInformation.website already has "http" or "https"

No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://vero.featherapp.net/... flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.android.chrome }

```
{ 
  val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(storeInformation.website))
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
  intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome")
  try {
      startActivity(intent)
  } catch (ex: ActivityNotFoundException) {
      // Chrome browser presumably not installed so allow user to choose instead
      Log.d(TAG, ex.localizedMessage)
      intent.setPackage(null)
      startActivity(intent)
  } catch (e : Exception){
      Log.d(TAG, e.localizedMessage)
}
```

Comment: Check this: https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle#access-installed-apps

Comment: have u fixes this issue @Alex Wesley ?

Comment: @Nininea Unfortunately no, I just used a WebView.